# Check If active Multiple gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I looking for a way to check multiple gameobject (numbers) and 5 parts to display, every part have 3 numbers they display random (0 is in all part), if O active in part1  do not display 0 in part 2,3,4 and 5 again but randomize another numbers in that part(2,3,4,5) it means I want to display 0  random in one part only in scene (either part 1,2,3,4or 5) and another number to random also.
[image]

I tried with the code below but I don't know what I am missing please help

```
private GameObject[] checkfirst;

[SerializeField]
private List < GameObject > objects = new List < GameObject > ();

public GameObject firstziro;

void Start()

{

  foreach(GameObject go in checkfirst) {
    if (go.activeSelf) {

      firstziro.gameObject.SetActive(false);

      int randomlyActiveObject = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, objects.Count);
      for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++) {
        objects[i].SetActive(i == randomlyActiveObject);
      }
    } else {

      firstziro.gameObject.SetActive(true);
      foreach(GameObject d in objects) {
        d.gameObject.SetActive(false);
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you’ll need to clarify the question a bit in order for people to help you. As is it’s a bit hard to follow. I’d suggest splitting it up into expected behaviour, what I tried, and what went wrong.

Comment: Yeah not clear what he wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not check all five part your checking 15 object into script is hard to handle, create the script to check only is section before random,  and then create another script to random 0,
[image]

```
[SerializeField] 
  private List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>(); 





public GameObject five; 

  void Start() 
  { 
      if( five.gameObject.activeSelf) 
      { 
           
foreach (GameObject g in objects) 
{ 
  g.gameObject.SetActive(false); 
} 

      } 
      else{ 
              int randomlyActiveObject = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, objects.Count); 
for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++) 
{ 
  objects[i].SetActive(i == randomlyActiveObject); 
} 
} 


      } 
  }
```